# Accessing feinCMS urls in django templates

Tags: python, django, feincms

I want to create a home page containing a list of feincms pages and linked to their url.

I am trying

```
{% url page_obj.get_absolute_url %}
```

which is throwing an error

```
Reverse for '/test/' with arguments '()'
```

The feincms page resides at localhost/test/

I have included the following in the urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'', include('feincms.contrib.preview.urls')),
    url(r'', include('feincms.urls')),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_absolute_url()` already returns the final URL. There's no need to pass it to the `{% url %}` templatetag. Just do a variable substition in your template:

```
<a href="{{ page_obj.get_absolute_url }}">
```